# wordpress custom post type with custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have added a custom post and a custom taxonomy to my wordpress theme.
problem is , when im trying to add new taxonomy im getting a javascript error:
(the taxonomy is added but screen needs to be refreshed before i can see it)

```
f.responses[0] is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

...or","")}}});f.children().css("backgroundColor","#f33")}return false});a("#submit...
```

This is my Code for adding the custom post and taxonomy

```
add_action('init', 'catalog_register');
function catalog_register() {

$labels=...;
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 101,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
      ); 
register_post_type( 'catalog' , $args );
}
```

here is my custom taxonomy code:

```
function create_catalog_taxonomies() {

    $labels =array(...);    

    register_taxonomy("product_category", array("catalog"), array(
            "hierarchical" => true, 
            "labels" => $labels, 
            'public' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'rewrite' => true
        ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_catalog_taxonomies', 0 );
```

what is wrong here ?

Comment: Where are you declaring your custom types? Do you put this into your `functions.php`? I've had problems when I've use a separate file. Maybe it helps.

Comment: yes im using functions.php , separate file does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already registered post type `catalog`, so just change the taxonomy registration to following syntax:

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels, 
    'public' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'rewrite' => true
    );
register_taxonomy('product_category', 'catalog', $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error also happens when the functions.php file contains a whitespace before the starting

Answer (score -2):

code for custom post type

```
function my_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Name', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Name', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Names', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Names', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Names', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Names', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Names', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Names', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Names Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array('title','author','excerpt','editor','thumbnail','revisions' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'Name', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_post_type', 0 );
```

> Custom Taxonomy

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_my_taxonomies', 0 );
function add_years_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy('years', 'repository', array(
'hierarchical' => true,'labels' => array('labels' => array(
'name' => _x( 'Years', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Year', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Years' ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Years' ),
'parent_item' => __( 'Parent ' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Year:' ),
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Year' ),
'update_item' => __( 'Update Year' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Year' ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New Year Name' ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Years' ),
),
'rewrite' => array(
'slug' => 'years', 
'with_front' => false, 
'hierarchical' => true 
),
));
}
```